# Strange error occured to python program using matplotlib and AutoDateLocator

Tags: python, matplotlib, date-formatting

I have created a python program that uses matplotlib to plot data and it had been working fine until today, an error occured. The program uses **AutoDateLocator** and **ConciseDateFormatter**. As you can see in the last line of the error log below, the received error is:

```
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Since it would be really difficult to post more details about my program functionality as well as the data used, I was wondering if there is an obvious solution to the above-mentioned problem, or if you could guide me to where I should look for the problem.

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1883,
> in **call**
>
> ```
> return self.func(*args)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\Uni\TUC
> studies\thesis\Code\python\test\myGUI_V3.py", line 841, in  plotMeas
>
> ```
> fig.tight_layout()
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 411, in
>
> wrapper
>
> ```
> return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 2613, in tight_layout
> kwargs = get_tight_layout_figure(
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py",
> line 303, in  get_tight_layout_figure
>
> ```
> kwargs = auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer,
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py",
> line 84, in
>
> auto_adjust_subplotpars
>
> ```
> bb += [ax.get_tightbbox(renderer, for_layout_only=True)]
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py",
> line 4155, in
>
> get_tightbbox
>
> ```
> bb_xaxis = self.xaxis.get_tightbbox(
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1109, in get_tightbbox
>
> ```
> ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1030, in _update_ticks
>
> ```
> minor_labels = self.minor.formatter.format_ticks(minor_locs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line
> 797, in format_ticks
>
> ```
> if len(np.unique(tickdate[:, level])) > 1:
> ```
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2
> were indexed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py",
> line 480, in
> _draw_idle
> self.draw()
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py",
> line 407, in  draw
> self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 1863, in draw
>
> ```
> mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
> 131, in
> _draw_list_compositing_images
> a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 411, in  wrapper
> return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py",
> line 2747, in draw
>
> ```
> mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
> 131, in
> _draw_list_compositing_images
> a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1164, in draw
>
> ```
> ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1030, in _update_ticks
>
> ```
> minor_labels = self.minor.formatter.format_ticks(minor_locs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line
> 797, in format_ticks
>
> ```
> if len(np.unique(tickdate[:, level])) > 1:
> ```
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2
> were indexed
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5.py",
> line 480, in
> _draw_idle
> self.draw()
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py",
> line 407, in  draw
> self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 1863, in draw
>
> ```
> mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
> 131, in
> _draw_list_compositing_images
> a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 411, in  wrapper
> return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py",
> line 2747, in draw
>
> ```
> mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
> 131, in
> _draw_list_compositing_images
> a.draw(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 41, in draw_wrapper
>
> ```
> return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1164, in draw
>
> ```
> ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line
> 1030, in _update_ticks
>
> ```
> minor_labels = self.minor.formatter.format_ticks(minor_locs)
> ```
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line
> 797, in format_ticks
>
> ```
> if len(np.unique(tickdate[:, level])) > 1:
> ```
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2
> were indexed

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was a problem of the setup of the **AutoDateLocator**. Because of the specific dataset, the minor ticks could not be set correctly, based on the values I had selected for *minticks*, *maxticks*, and for the *intervald* tuples chosen. As a result, when the **ConciseDateFormatter** tried to use the locator for the minor ticks, the above-mentioned error occured.

When used a simple DateFormatter, there was no error, but neither the minor ticks, nor their labels appeared on the plot.

Comment: This may be worth reporting to matplotlib with a self contained example.  It probably should error out more gracefully at least.